# Switch on one true expression c#

Tags: c#

I would have liked to do something like

```
switch(true) {
    case box1.Checked:
       do_something(); break;
    case box2.Checked:
       do_something_else();
       and_some_more(); break;
    default:
       complain_loudly();
}
```

But that is not allowed in c#; it is in php.

Is there a neater way, besides a

```
if (box1.Checked) {
   do_something();
} else if (box2.checked)
  ...
```

?

Comment: C# does not support variable cases like that. What's wrong with the simple if/else if? It's probably the same number of lines of code.

Comment: if you need multiple checkboxes use checkboxlist

Comment: You should definitely use VB. It's really great and does all things https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_3

Answer (score 14):

With C# 7 using `case` with `when`. See also [The case statement and the when clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-the-case-statement-and-the-when-clause)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Box box1 = new Box();
            Box box2 = new Box();
            box2.Checked = true;
            switch (true)
            {
                case true when box1.Checked:
                    Console.WriteLine("box1 is checked");
                    break;
                case true when box2.Checked:
                    Console.WriteLine("box2 is checked");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("neither box checked");
                    break;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    class Box
    {
        public bool Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
box2 is checked
```

Comment: +1 this is a neat trick! As someone who uses both C# and VB, I think C# could really pick up a trick or two from VB in this area (and it seems it will get there eventually given the constant improvement in pattern matching over the years).

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this - find fist checked checkbox from collection and then switch-case by name of checked control...
Something like this:

```
var checkedCb = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked).First();

switch (checkedCb.Name)
{
    case "cbOne":
        break;
    case "cbTwo":
        break;
    default:
        break;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP seems to resolve a switch differently than C#.

In C# you **switch over an expression and use the cases to define possible constant results of the expression you switched over**. The neat thing about the C# switch is that it might be optimized which requires the cases to be constant expressions.

1. Your first Problem is that your cases are not constant.
2. As a result of point 1: If both of your checkboxes are checked which one should be executed? This is a problem that would cause a runtime issue and cannot be evaluated at compile time. C# will not allow multiple cases of the same value.

I don't want to provide any examples of optimization here, simply because I would tell a lot of lies. If you want to know more about these optimizations you may read up to Eric Lipper's blog post about it:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/

As a solution: **KISS**
**K**eep **i**t **s**imple **s**tupid - meaning - use an `if else`.

---

EDIT:
I don't think it adds to readability nor simplicity of your code. This is basically just me trying to do something weird like the switch statement you know from PHP. 
<strike>Please don't use it.</strike> I wouldn't recommend using it.
(It takes more space and time, initially and during each call, than a simple `if else`)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private CheckBox[] _checkboxes;
        private Dictionary<int, Action> _checkboxActions = new Dictionary<int, Action>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();

            checkboxes.Add(CheckBox1);
            checkboxes.Add(CheckBox2);

            _checkboxes = checkboxes.ToArray();

            _checkboxActions.Add(CheckBox1.GetHashCode(), OnCheckBox1Checked);
            _checkboxActions.Add(CheckBox2.GetHashCode(), OnCheckBox2Checked);
        }

        public void InvokeCheckboxActions()
        {
            Action action;

            foreach(var checkbox in _checkboxes)
            {
                if(checkbox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    int checkboxPtr = checkbox.GetHashCode();

                    if(_checkboxActions.TryGetValue(checkboxPtr, out action))
                    {
                        action();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnCheckBox1Checked()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checkbox 1 was checked");
        }

        private void OnCheckBox2Checked()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checkbox 2 was checked");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this code will have desired behavior.

```
public enum Mode { None, Break, Continue };

public sealed class Branch<T>
{
    public Mode Mode { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
    public Action Action { get; }

    public Branch(T value, Action action, Mode mode = Mode.None)
    {
        Value = value;
        Action = action;
        Mode = mode;
    }
}

public static class CaseHelper
{
    public static void Switch<T>(T condition, params Branch<T>[] branches)
    {
        bool Continue = false;
        foreach (var branch in branches)
        {
            if (branch.Value.Equals(condition) || Continue)
            {
                branch.Action();
            }

            if (branch.Mode == Mode.Break) break;
            Continue = branch.Mode == Mode.Continue;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
CaseHelper.Switch(true, new Branch<bool>(box1.Checked, doSomething1), new Branch<bool>(box2.Checked, () => doSomething2()));
```

but it looks not very elegant

P.S.:
We can add implicit conversion operator to Branch

```
public static implicit operator Branch<T>(Tuple<T, Action, Mode> triple)
{
    return new Branch<T>(triple.Item1, triple.Item2, triple.Item3);
}

public static implicit operator Branch<T>(Tuple<T, Action> duple)
{
    return new Branch<T>(duple.Item1, duple.Item2);
}
```

and use something like this:

```
CaseHelper.Switch(true, 
    (Branch<bool>)Tuple.Create<bool, Action>(box1.Checked, doSomething1),
    (Branch<bool>)Tuple.Create<bool, Action, Mode>(box2.Checked, () => doSomething2(), Mode.Break)
);
```

Comment: We were both trying to link checkbox states to behaviour. Glad that we both came to the conculsion that it doesn't look very elegant :)